# update and modify data in database periodically php

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

language: php
framework: cakephp
database: mysql

Question:
how can I update and modify data in database every 5 minutes? Is there any tech like java timer, schedule in PHP. Or use database trigger some process to achieve this. Which solution is recommended?

Example:
One request send to server then store the request in database, after 5 mins if there is not any matching result. The request status field in database must be mark as expired. and at same time send respond message to user, said "sorry the request has been expired" **Each request must have its own timer**. So every incoming request need to be timed 5 mins after 5 mins send respond to user and make the request as expired status.

Any keyword, solution, hint will be nice!

Thx

Comment: Read this tutorial regarding [cron job](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/)

Comment: How is this "after 5 mins send respond to user" supposed to work? Does the server actively send something somewhere after exactly 5 minutes, or do you just need to expire an item in the database?

Comment: Thank you for reply. there is some field called status in table will be marked as expired status. At the same time, the php will send respond message to user said "Sorry the request expired"

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the MYSQL event scheduler (for your job to update your requests)

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

the syntax for creating a job is easy

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SECONDS
    DO
      call your_update_routine;
```

The other part of this is you need to refresh the web page after 5 minutes, I would use javascript for this..

see: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/autofresh.shtml

The example is for a continious refresh , you will need to alter it to only refresh once (say if the date returned from the database is under 5 minutes old)

Then on refresh of your page you simply need to check the status of your request.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you could create cronjobs in combination with CakePHP console scripts. Look at :
[The CakePHP Console](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1106/The-CakePHP-Console) for more information on the different scripts available.

You can then setup all of your cronjobs to call different Cakephp scripts, or run 1 script that figures out what should be updated.